# Regex capture between certain characters

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I'm quite new to Python and regex. I'm almost there but fail to fix this issue after 6 hours. Hopefully someone can help.

My string is as follows:

```
str_1 =  & peers & & apples & & lemon juice & & Strawberries & & Mellon &
```

I would like a new list that contains: `['peers','apples','lemon juice','Strawberries','Mellon']`. So without all the whitespace and the `&` signs.

My code is as follows:

```
list_1 = re.compile(r'(?<=&)(.*?)(?=&)').findall(str_1)
```

However, I get something like this:

```
list_1 =  [' peers ', ' ', ' apples ', ' ', ' lemon juice ', ' ', ' Strawberries ', ' ', ' Mellon']
```

Can someone please help to get:

```
['peers','apples','lemon juice','Strawberries','Mellon']
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regexes for this

```
>>> str_1 =  '& peers & & apples & & lemon juice & & Strawberries & & Mellon &'
>>> ls = [x.strip() for x in str_1.split('&')]
>>> ls = [x for x in ls if x]
>>> ls
['peers', 'apples', 'lemon juice', 'Strawberries', 'Mellon']
```

If you still want a regex, then

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^& ][^&]*[^& ]', str_1)
['peers', 'apples', 'lemon juice', 'Strawberries', 'Mellon']
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have to use a regex**, you can use

```py
re.findall(r'[^&\s]+(?:[^&]*[^&\s])?', str_1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CpnZfL/1). *Details*:

- `[^&\s]+` - one or more chars other than `&` and whitespace
  -`(?:[^&]*[^&\s])?` - an optional sequence of any chars other than `&` and then a char other than a `&` or whitespace.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ySq4WV):

```py
import re
str_1 = "& peers & & apples & & lemon juice & & Strawberries & & Mellon & "
print( re.findall(r'[^&\s]+(?:[^&]*[^&\s])?', str_1) )
# => ['peers', 'apples', 'lemon juice', 'Strawberries', 'Mellon']
```

**A non-regex solution** can look like

```py
[x.strip() for x in str_1.split('&') if x.strip()]
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/PnSe5k). Here, you split a string with `&` chars and only keep the items that are not empty or are all whitespace with leading/trailing spaces stripped.